# Segmentation Fault in Rails Console with Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault, rails-console

I'm encountering a segmentation fault error when running rails console in my Rails 5.2.8 application with Ruby 2.6.3. The issue arises when I attempt to access any database record, for instance, using `Consultation.last`. Here's the console output (with personal path details omitted):

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 76743
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.8)
[1] pry(main)> con = Consultation.last 
.../gems/pg-1.4.1/lib/pg/connection.rb:591: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x000...
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [-darwin23]
```

This is followed by a detailed crash report and control frame information.

Steps I've already Taken:

- Reinstalled Ruby using both rbenv and chruby.
- Ensured all gems are compatible and up-to-date with the current Rails version.
- Checked logs for specific error patterns or additional information.

Constraints:

Upgrading Ruby or Rails is currently not an option due to project constraints.

Questions:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?
Are there known issues with the pg gem (version 1.4.1) compatibility with this Ruby version?
Any recommendations for troubleshooting or resolving this segmentation fault?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried already to stop / restart your running spring preloader with `bin/spring stop`?

Comment: I did try, but unfortunately didn't resolve the issue. The segmentation fault persists even after restarting the spring preloader. Thanks for your suggestion @HolgerJust

Comment: Both versions – Ruby and Ruby on Rails – are not on their latest patch version. Did you consider updating them?

Comment: Also the pg gem also has some updates, at least one of which resolves a possible segfault.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys. I've updated, but the segmentation fault still occurs. Interestingly, colleagues with the same setup (Mac M1) and gem versions don't have this issue. It seems like a machine-specific configuration might be the cause? Any thoughts on what to check or adjust on my setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the postgres server working fine? Can you connect and do some querying manually? It could be a System Lib problem.